# Removing lines from yaml file based on patterns found in another file

Tags: awk

I am a inexperienced with awk. I need to delete lines in a yaml file based on strings in a second file. Awk, bash or sed are the only acceptable solutions; no perl, python, ruby or libraries please.

I started with the following which matches the first pattern only skipping or missing all subsequent.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { pat[$0];next } NR>FNR { for (p in pat) if ($0 !~ p) {print;next} }' patterns yaml_file
```

The input files are extracts of the source file.

pattern strings file

```
#Remove the entire yaml line for the following
kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration
openshift.io/backup-registry-hostname

#remove the entire yaml block for the following
managedFields
status
```

and yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"apps.openshift.io/v1","kind":"DeploymentConfig","metadata":{"annotations":{"openshift.io/backup-registry-hostname":"docker-registry.default.svc:5000",,"spec":}
      openshift.io/backup-registry-hostname: docker-registry.default.svc:5000
  status:
    ingress:
    - conditions:
metadata:
  selfLink: ""
```

Comment: Reduce your example to a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (e.g. maybe 5 lines in your "pattern strings" file and maybe 10-15 lines of yaml) and the expected output given that input and you'll have a much better chance of getting an answer. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First of all a some general things:

1. I'm (kinda) sorry, but the first is **RTFM**. There is [this **awesome** doc for gawk](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_toc.html), but also [mawk's man page](https://astro.uni-bonn.de/%7Esysstw/lfa_html/starbase/mawk.1.html) is a good starting point.
2. `NR==FNR` is only true once: With the very last line of the first input file (patterns), because `NR` is the line number over all files, `FNR` is the line number in the current file.

But since the task was funny and I like awk, here's my solution (valid for `mawk` and flavors superseding its function set, such as `gwak`). Personally, I would split the patterns in two files (see below), because otherwise you have to split then inside awk. It's possible, but since it is based on a string match in a comment-line it's a bad approach.

#### Solution based on your input

You should store your awk source in a file. It makes it easier to debug and many editors provide highlighting. Like `reduce_yaml.awk` and call it with `awk -f reduce_yaml.awk patterns yaml_file`

```
{
    if(FILENAME == "patterns"){
        if($0 ~ /^#.*block/) {
            inpat = "blocks"
        } else if($0 ~ /^#.*line/) {
            inpat = "lines"
        } else if($0 !~ /^#|^$/){
            if(inpat == "lines"){
                patterns_lines[$0] = 1
            } else if(inpat == "blocks"){
                patterns_blocks[$0] = 1
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(beginwith && substr($0, 1, length(beginwith)) != beginwith){
            beginwith = ""
        } else if(beginwith){
            next
        }

        for (p in patterns_lines){
            if ($0 ~ p) next
        }
        for (p in patterns_blocks){
            if ($0 ~ p) {
                beginwith = sprintf("%*s", match($0, /[^ ]/) + 1, "")
                next
            }
        }
        print
    }
}
```

#### Solution with split pattern files (`patterns_blocks` and `patterns_lines`)

The call is `awk -f reduce_yaml.awk yaml_file` with the two patterns files as mentioned in the headline being present in the same directory.

```
BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < "patterns_lines") > 0){
        if(line !~ /^#|^$/) patterns_lines[line] = 1
    }
    close("patterns_lines.txt")

    while ((getline line < "patterns_blocks") > 0){
        if(line !~ /^#|^$/)  patterns_blocks[line] = 1
    }
    close("patterns_blocks.txt")
}

{
    if(beginwith && substr($0, 1, length(beginwith)) != beginwith){
        beginwith = ""
    } else if(beginwith){
        next
    }

    for (p in patterns_lines){
        if ($0 ~ p) next
    }
    for (p in patterns_blocks){
        if ($0 ~ p) {
            beginwith = sprintf("%*s", match($0, /[^ ]/) + 1, "")
            next
        }
    }
    print
}
```